# Why to define the constructor parameter of Reader as a function?

Tags: haskell, reader-monad

When learning the Reader Monad, I find that it is defined as:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Monad (Reader r) where
  return a = Reader $ \_ -> a
  m >>= k  = Reader $ \r -> runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

I want to known why using function as constructor parameter instead of something else such as a tuple:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: (r, a) }

instance Monad (Reader r) where
  -- Here I cannot get r when defining return function, 
  -- so does that's the reason that must using a function whose input is an "r"?
  return a = Reader (r_unknown, a) 
  m >>= k = Reader (fst $ runReader m) (f (snd $ runReader m))
```

According to the Reader definition, we need a "environment" which we can use to generate a "value". I think a Reader type should contain the information of "environment" and "value", so the tuple seems perfect.

Comment: Just to make your doubt clearer: why did you think specifically of a tuple?

Comment: It sounds like you answer your own question ...?

Comment: @JustinL. I suspect there is a more interesting underlying question that the OP didn't explicitly state -- whether it makes sense to use a pair for the same purposes that we use `Reader`.

Comment: @duplode Because according to the Reader definition, we need a "environment" which we can use to generate a "value". I think a Reader type should contain the information of "environment" and "value", so the tuple seems perfect..

Comment: @hliu That's what I suspected :) I'm writing an answer addressing that.

Comment: @duplode Yes, I tried and want to constrain the r with class "Monoid" (so I can give a mempty to it when defining the "return"), but it seems really like the "Writer" monad.. Maybe the meaning of Reader is using the "environment" as input to generate a value, but Writer can just generate the "environment" itself using "tell" function. Sorry for my poor english..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't mention it in the question, but I guess you thought specifically of using a pair for defining `Reader` because it also makes sense to think of that as a way of providing a fixed environment. Let's say we have an earlier result in the `Reader` monad:

```
return 2 :: Reader Integer Integer
```

We can use this result to do further calculations with the fixed environment (and the `Monad` methods guarantee it remains fixed throughout the chain of `(>>=)`):

```
GHCi> runReader (return 2 >>= \x -> Reader (\r -> x + r)) 3
5
```

(If you substitute the definitions of `return`, `(>>=)` and `runReader` in the expression above and simplify it, you will see exactly how it reduces to `2 + 3`.)

Now, let's follow your suggestion and define:

```
newtype Env r a = Env { runEnv :: (r, a) }
```

If we have an environment of type `r` and a previous result of type `a`, we can make an `Env r a` out of them...

```
Env (3, 2) :: Env Integer Integer
```

... and we can also get a new result from that:

```
GHCi> (\(r, x) -> x + r) . runEnv $ Env (3, 2)
5
```

The question, then, is whether we can capture this pattern through the `Monad` interface. The answer is no. While there *is* a `Monad` instance for pairs, it does something quite different:

```
newtype Writer r a = Writer { Writer :: (r, a) }

instance Monoid r => Monad (Writer r) where
    return x = (mempty, x)
    m >>= f = Writer 
        . (\(r, x) -> (\(s, y) -> (mappend r s, y)) $ f x)
        $ runWriter m
```

The `Monoid` constraint is needed so that we can use `mempty` (which solves the problem that you noticed of having to create a `r_unknown` out of nowhere) and `mappend` (which makes it possible to combine the first elements of the pair in a way that doesn't violate the monad laws). This `Monad` instance, however, does something very different than what the `Reader` one does. The first element of the pair isn't fixed (it is subject to change, as we `mappend` other generated values to it) and we don't use it to compute the second element of the pair (in the definition above, `y` does not depend neither on `r` nor on `s`). `Writer` is a logger; the `r` values here are output, not input.

---

There is one way, however, in which your intuition is justified: we can't make a reader-like monad using a pair, but we can make a reader-like *co*monad. To put it very loosely, [`Comonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:Comonad) is what you get when you turn the `Monad` interface upside down:

```
-- This is slightly different than what you'll find in Control.Comonad,
-- but it boils down to the same thing.
class Comonad w where
    extract :: w a -> a                 -- compare with return
    (=>>) :: w a -> (w a -> b) -> w b   -- compare with (>>=)
```

We can give the `Env` we had abandoned a `Comonad` instance:

```
newtype Env r a = Env { runEnv :: (r, a) }

instance Comonad (Env r) where
    extract (Env (_, x)) = x
    w@(Env (r, _)) =>> f = Env (r, f w)
```

That allows us to write the `2 + 3` example from the beginning in terms of `(=>>)`:

```
GHCi> runEnv $ Env (3, 2) =>> ((\(r, x) -> x + r) . runEnv) 
(3,5)
```

One way to see why this works is noting that an `a -> Reader r b` function (i.e. what you give to `Reader`'s `(>>=)`) is essentially the same thing that an `Env r a -> b` one (i.e. what you give to `Env`'s `(=>>)`):

```
a -> Reader r b
a -> (r -> b)     -- Unwrap the Reader result
r -> (a -> b)     -- Flip the function
(r, a) -> b       -- Uncurry the function
Env r a -> b      -- Wrap the argument pair
```

As further evidence of that, here is a function that changes one into the other:

```
GHCi> :t \f -> \w -> (\(r, x) -> runReader (f x) r) $ runEnv w
\f -> \w -> (\(r, x) -> runReader (f x) r) $ runEnv w
  :: (t -> Reader r a) -> Env r t -> a
GHCi> -- Or, equivalently:
GHCi> :t \f -> uncurry (flip (runReader . f)) . runEnv
\f -> uncurry (flip (runReader . f)) . runEnv
  :: (a -> Reader r c) -> Env r a -> c
```

To wrap things up, here is a slightly longer example, with `Reader` and `Env` versions side-by-side:

```
GHCi> :{
GHCi| flip runReader 3 $
GHCi|     return 2 >>= \x ->
GHCi|     Reader (\r -> x ^ r) >>= \y ->
GHCi|     Reader (\r -> y - r)
GHCi| :}
5
GHCi> :{
GHCi| extract $
GHCi|     Env (3, 2) =>> (\w ->
GHCi|     (\(r, x) -> x ^ r) $ runEnv w) =>> (\z ->
GHCi|     (\(r, x) -> x - r) $ runEnv z)
GHCi| :}
5
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all note that your bind function is wrong and would not compile.

If the `Reader` were defined as you describe with a tuple, there would be problems:

1. The monad laws would be violated, e.g. left identity, which states that:

   ```
   return a >>= f == f a
   ```

or the right identity:

```
    m >>= return == m
```

would be broken, depending on the implmentation of `>>=` because `>>=` would *forget* either the first tuple element of the first argument or the second, i.e. if the implmentation would be:

```
(Reader (mr, mv)) >>= f =
    let (Reader (fr, fv)) = f mv 
    in Reader (mr, fv)
```

then we would always lose the reader value that comes out of `f` (aka `fr`) and otherwise if `>>=` would be

```
(Reader (mr, mv)) >>= f =
    let (Reader (fr, fv)) = f mv 
    in Reader (fr, fv) 
           -- ^^^ tiny difference here ;)
```

we would always lose `mr`.

2. A `Reader` is some action, that may `ask` for a constant value, which cannot be changed by another monadic action, which is **read-only**.

But when defined with a tuple, we could super-easy overwrite the reader value, e.g. whith this function:

```
    tell :: x -> BadReader x ()
    tell x = BadReader (x, ())
```

If a reader is instead defined with a function, this is impossible (try it)

3. Also, that *enviroment* is actually not required **before** converting a `Reader` to a pure value (aka running the Reader), so from this alone it makes sense to use a function instead of a tuple.

When using a tuple, we would have to provide the `Reader` value even before we actually run an action.

You can see that in your `return` definition, you even point out the problem, where the `r_unknown` comes from ...

To get a btter intuition, let's assume a `Reader` action that returns the `Person`s with a certain `age` from the `Addressbook`:

```
  data Person = MkPerson {name :: String, age :: Int}
  type Addressbook = [Person]

  personsWithThisAge :: Int -> Reader Addressbook [Person]
  personsWithThisAge a = do
    addressbook <- ask
    return (filter (\p -> age p == a) addressbook)
```

This `personsWithAge` function returns a `Reader` action and since it only `ask`s for the `Addressbook`, it is like a function that accepts an addressbook and gives back a `[Person]` list,
so it is natural to define a reader as just that, a function from some input to a result.

We could rewrite this `Reader` action to be a function of the `Addressbook` like this:

```
  personsWithThisAgeFun :: Int -> Addressbook -> [Person]
  personsWithThisAgeFun a addressbook =
    filter (\p -> age p == a) addressbook
```

But why invent `Reader`??

The real value of `Reader` shows when combining several functions like e.g. `personsWithThisAge`, that all depend on (the same) one constant `Addressbook`.

Using a `Reader` we don't have to explicitly pass some `Addressbook` around, individual `Reader` actions don't even have any way at all to modify the `Addressbook` - `Reader` guarantees us, that every action uses **the same, unmodified** `Addressbook`, and all a `Reader` action can ever to with the *environment* is `ask` for it.

The only way to implement this, with these guarantees is with a function.

Also if you look at the monad instances that are included in the standard library, you will see that `(r ->)` is a monad; actually it is identical to the `Reader` monad apart from some technical differences.

Now the structure you describe with the tuple is actually pretty close to a `Writer` monad, what is **write-only** , but that's out of scope.