# Writer monad and unsequence

Tags: haskell, monads, comonad, writer-monad

I am using the `Writer` monad to keep track of an error ("collision") flag on arbitrary values (such as `Int`). Once the flag is set it is "sticky" and attaches itself to all values produced as a result of any operation with the marked one.

Sometimes the collision flag is associated with individual values, sometimes I would like to associate with composite structures such as lists. Of course, once the collision flag is set for a whole list, it also makes sense to assume it is set for an individual element. So for a writer monad `m` I need the two following operations:

```
sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]
unsequence :: m [a] -> [m a]
```

The first one is defined in the Prelude, while the second one has to be defined. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342863/unsequence-monad-function-within-haskell) is a good discussion of how it could be defined using *comonads*. A native comonad implementation does not preserve the state. Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module Foo where    

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Comonad

unsequence :: (Comonad w, Monad m) => w [a] -> [m a]
unsequence = map return . extract

instance Monoid Bool where
    mempty = False
    mappend = (||)

type CM = Writer Bool
type CInt = CM Int

instance (Monoid w) => Comonad (Writer w) where
    extract x = fst $ runWriter x
    extend f wa = do { tell $ execWriter wa ; return (f wa)}

mkCollision :: t -> Writer Bool t
mkCollision x = do (tell True) ; return x

unsequence1 :: CM [Int] -> [CInt]
unsequence1 a = let (l,f) = runWriter a in
              map (\x -> do { tell f ; return x}) l

el = mkCollision [1,2,3]

ex2:: [CInt]      
ex2 = unsequence el
ex1 = unsequence1 el
```

The `ex1` produces the correct value, while `ex2` output is incorrectly not preserving collision flag:

```
*Foo> ex1
[WriterT (Identity (1,True)),WriterT (Identity (2,True)),WriterT (Identity (3,True))]
*Foo> ex2
[WriterT (Identity (1,False)),WriterT (Identity (2,False)),WriterT (Identity (3,False))]
*Foo>
```

In view of this I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to define `unsequence` using monadic and comonadic operators, not specific to `Writer`?
2. Is there is a more elegant implementation of the `extend` function above, perhaps similar to [this one](https://www.olivierverdier.com/posts/2014/12/31/reader-writer-monad-comonad/)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you further motivate the need for `unsequence`? Why isn't binding and then pattern-matching on the resulting list (which, as you observe, will correctly propagate your dirty bit to any computation done with the list elements you bound in the pattern match) good enough?

Comment: Basically, it is a matter of convenience. I would like to use a mix of lifted and unlifted functions on individual values and lists. For example, some function could generate a list of elements of type [Int], then I would like to use binary function `f: CInt->Cint` to map over this list.

Comment: How does `unsequence` make that more convenient? For `action :: M [Int]` and `f :: Int -> Int`, the two expressions are `map f <$> action`  and `mapM (f <$>) (unsequence action)`; of the two, I much prefer the former even before I look at whether `unsequence` is implementable or not. Or if you meant `f' :: Int -> M Int`, then the two are `action >>= mapM f'` vs `mapM (>>= f') (unsequence action)`, and again I prefer the one that doesn't use `unsequence`.

Comment: I'm not saying `unsequence` is unwarranted. I am just encouraging you to try to sharpen your description of why it's needed -- the more clear your goals are, the better advice folks can give about how to achieve your goals!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The `ex1` produces correct value, while `ex2` output is incorrectly not preserving collision flag:

`unsequence` (and, as a consequence, `ex2`) doesn't work because it throws away the `Writer` log.

```
unsequence :: (Comonad w, Monad m) => w [a] -> [m a]
unsequence = map return . extract
```

`extract` for your `Comonad` instance gives the result of the computation, discarding the log. `return` adds a `mempty` log to the bare results. That being so, the flags are cleared in `ex2`.

`unsequence1`, on the other hand, does what you want. That clearly doesn't have anything to do with `Comonad` (your definition doesn't use its methods); rather, `unsequence1` works because... it's actually `sequence`! Under the hood, `Writer` is just a pair of a result and a (monoidal) log. If you have a second look at `unsequence1` with that in mind, you will note that (modulo irrelevant details) it does essentially the same thing than `sequence` for pairs -- it annotates the values in the other functor with the log:

```
GHCi> sequence (3, [1..10])
[(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9),(3,10)]
```

In fact, `Writer` already has a `Traversable` instance just like that, so you don't even need to define it:

```
GHCi> import Control.Monad.Writer
GHCi> import Data.Monoid -- 'Any' is your 'Bool' monoid.
GHCi> el = tell (Any True) >> return [1,2,3] :: Writer Any [Int]
GHCi> sequence el
[WriterT (Identity (1,Any {getAny = True})),WriterT (Identity (2,Any {getAny = True})),WriterT (Identity (3,Any {getAny = True}))]
```

It is worth mentioning that `sequence` isn't an essentially monadic operation -- the `Monad` constraint in `sequence` is unnecessarily restrictive. The real deal is [`sequenceA`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html), which only requires an `Applicative` constraint on the inner functor. (If the outer `Functor` -- i.e. the one with the `Traversable` instance -- is like `Writer w` in that it always "holds" exactly one value, then you don't even need `Applicative`, but [that's another story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31978596/2751851).)

> Is it possible to define 'unsequence' using monadic and comonadic operators, not specific to 'Writer'

As discussed above, you don't actually want `unsequence`. There is a class called [`Distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html) that does provide `unsequence` (under the name of `distribute`); however, there is relatively little overlap between things with `Distributive` instances and things with `Traversable` ones, and in any case it doesn't essentially involve comonads.

> Is there is a more elegant implementatoin of extend function above, perhaps similar to this one?

Your `Comonad` instance is fine (it does follow [the comonad laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html#t:Comonad)), except that you don't actually need the `Monoid` constraint in it. The pair comonad is usually known as [`Env`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Env.html#t:EnvT); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311754/2751851) for discussion of what it does.

Comment: "unsequence1 works because... it's actually sequence". My brains are leaking out my ears. This is way too cool.

Comment: @DanielWagner `Traversable` is a beautiful thing :)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! It was indeed surprising that two seemingly inverse operations could be both mapped to `sequence`!

Comment: @krokodil matrix transpose function is its own inverse.